# Oracle Connect By Prior for Recursive Query Syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

Suppose I had the following table in my oracle DB:

```
ID:    Name:     Parent_ID:
123    a         234
345    b         123
234    c         234
456    d         345
567    e         567
678    f         567
```

And what I would like to do is find, for each `ID` the `ULTIMATE parent ID` (described as row, that when you go up, recursively, based upon `Parent_ID` the row where you finally get that `ID = Parent_ID`).

So, for example, 345's parent is 123 and 123's parent is 234 and 234's parent is 234 (meaning it is the top of the chain), therefore 345's ultimate parent is 234 - I hope this makes sense...

So, my result should look as follows:

```
ID:    Name:     Ult_Parent_ID:    Ult_Parent_Name:
123    a         234               c
345    b         234               c
234    c         234               c
456    d         234               c
567    e         567               e
678    f         567               e
```

I just found out about Oracle `Connect By` statments today, so this is completely new to me, but I'm imagining my query would have to look SOMETHING as follows:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Parent_ID as Ult_Parent_ID, 
   (SELECT Name from MyTable t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.Parent_ID) as Ult_Parent_Name
FROM MyTable t1
CONNECT BY PRIOR Parent_ID = ID;
```

Now, like I said, this is my first stab at this kind of SQL - **THIS DOES NOT WORK** (I get the following error `[1]: ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data` and it highlights the table name in the SQL editor), and I also don't know where / how to use the `START WITH` clause for this kind of query, but the logic of it seems correct to me.

Please help / help point me in the right direction!!!

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please explain "*does not work*". Are you getting any errors or just wrong results?

Comment: Sorry - Bad explanataion - I get the following error `[1]: ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data` and it highlights the table name in the query... Sorry about that... I'll also update the Q now

Comment: Try to add `NOCYCLE` clause and see whether you agree with the result.

Comment: If you have control over database content it *may* be to your advantage to have *root* row with `Parent_ID` as `NULL`, i.e. no parent at all.

Comment: Thanks @PM77-1 - Yes, **thank you for that tip** it worked with the nocycle clause and gave me the correct results... I still don't know how to 1) Make it work for all the records (not only for 1 record to check) and 2)make it work without that clause. But, yes, the data looks correct. Also, unfortunately, I have no control over the DB - I just have query rights...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the CONNECT_BY_ROOT is what you need:

```
select x.*, t2.name ultimate_name
from
(
  select t.id, t.name, CONNECT_BY_ROOT parent_id ultimate_id
  from toto t
  start with t.id = t.parent_id
  connect by nocycle prior id = parent_id
) x, toto t2
where x.ultimate_id = t2.id
;
```

This gives:

```
456 d   234 c
345 b   234 c
123 a   234 c
234 c   234 c
678 f   567 e
567 e   567 e
```

Comment: This did the trick!!!! - Thank you very much!!! - Would **NEVER** have figured this out on my own!!!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Parent_ID as Ult_Parent_ID, 
   (SELECT Name from MyTable t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.Parent_ID) as Ult_Parent_Name, 
   LEVEL
FROM MyTable t1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE Parent_ID = PRIOR ID
START WITH Parent_ID = ID;
```

I believe that we have to use `NOCYCLE` because of how your roots are defined.

I added pseudo-column `LEVEL` just for illustration purposes.  You **do not** have to have it in your final query.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8b2c1/2) with your test data

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH for sticking with me and answering this Q, but I'm still getting that error - `[1]: ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data` and it's highlighting the table name in the editor. It goes away if I add in the `NOCYCLE` clause... Is it possible the DB was configured to not allow this or something???

Comment: Also in addition to the obvious cycle ( `Parent_ID = ID` ) your actual database could have multi-row cycles. Like this two-row: `10, 20` and `20,10`. If the latter is indeed the case you will **have to** use `NOCYCLE` clause.

Comment: I do not see how to avoid `NOCYCLE` clause without changing the data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and advice - I just couldn't get this to work correctly - Even with the `NOCYCLE` clause... Eventually @Emmanuel's solution proved to give me exactly what I wanted...

Answer (score 1):

A CONNECT BY will give you the immediate parent but to get the ultimate parent I would use a [recursive subquery](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#BCEJGIBG). (`CONNECT_BY_ROOT` as explained by Emmanuel also works)

```
WITH r (id, parent, ultimate_parent, name, ultimate_parent_name, lvl) as
   (SELECT id, parent_id AS parent, parent_id AS ultimate_parent, name, name as ultimate_parent_name, 0 lvl
    FROM mytable
       WHERE parent_id = id -- identifies a root
UNION ALL
    SELECT m.id, r.id, ultimate_parent, m.name, r.ultimate_parent_name, r.lvl + 1
    FROM r join mytable m on m.parent_id = r.id  -- joins child with parent
    WHERE m.parent_id <> m.id -- to avoid cycles
   )
SELECT * FROM r ;
```

The first part of the subquery fetches the roots and the second part connects the children. `Parent` is the immediate parent and `ultimate_parent`, the ultimate parent.

Comment: `CONNECT BY` works on any hierarchy. It's what was used in Oracle before recursive factored sub-queries were implemented in Oracle 11.2.

Comment: I'm trying this query and getting the error `[1]: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` with `SELECT m.id` part highlighted... Does that make any sense to you??

Comment: Thanks for your help, but @Emmanuel's solution finally proved accurate for what I wanted. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

create table test_data (order_number number(10), line_id number(10), parent_line_id number (10));

```
              insert into test_data values (1000, 101, 100);

              insert into test_data values (1000, 100, '');

              insert into test_data values (3000, 301, 300);

              insert into test_data values (3000, 300, '');


              select * from test_data

              select * from test_data 
              where order_number in (1000,3000) 
              start with parent_line_id is null 
              connect by prior line_id= parent_line_id
```